# can't get message using twilio

Tags: sms, ip-address, twilio

I'm using Twilio to send and respond to messages. It was working normally, but since we moved to bay area the responding function doesn't work now.
So what happens is when the user send message to us(the IP address of our own computers) from their phones,  our server can't receive anything. When we check our Twilio account, we know that the msg was indeed sent to the Twilio server. So we think it's the problem of linking between Twilio server and our IP address. We are suspecting that the IP address is virtual IP address here, which makes Twilio server can't find us. Is our suspection correct? if yes, what should we do? If not, what would be the possible problems?

Apologize for having a description not very clear, but it's pretty much everything of the problem. Please tell me if you need any additional information.

Comment: When you say your "own computers" are you referring to a server, or personal computers?

Comment: Hi thank you first. I mean personal computers

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a [dynamic dns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service. Then you need to find what port Twilio sends the SMSs to the client(your computer), and make sure your firewall is forwarding that port to your computer. Odds are this is a firewall issue, especially since you say everything worked before you moved. Has there been a change in your network setup? You need to be aware of both hardware and software firewalls in your setup.

Comment: Hey I think this is not a problem of port, since it can't event connect to the server at all, eg."Safari can't connect to the server 192.168.1.1"(I made it up).And in the terminal, we don't see any new action popping up when we send the msg. Beside, when we run the application, we explicitly set the port as 8080.
Just add some new information so you have a better sense. Thank you!

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Are you saying Safari cannot connect to the Twilio API server? Thats probably normal ince the API probably isn't configured to receive browser GET requests.You also said you don't think it is a port problem, but what about your IP address?

Comment: Yes we connected to the internet. I was saying safari can't connect to the IP address of my computer. Yes we think it's very likely the problem of our IP address. We tried different IP address: the one we found from our system info; the one we found from the website www.myipaddress.com. But none of them works. When we send message from our phone, the terminal doesn't even show there's a request

Answer (score 0):

How is the firewall configured on your router? You need to forward requests to your router to your local IP address. 
 Example:
 My local ip is 192.168.1.5 
my external ip is 245.932.4.3 (This is the value you get from myipaddress.com) 
Thus you need to set your router (which has ip 245.932.4.3) to forward requests on port x (where x= the twilio outgoing port) to 192.168.1.5

Comment: On a mac, in the terminal type `ifconfig | grep inet` to get your local ip

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! Really appreciate it. It's indeed where the problem is! THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome! Gald it worked out! I'd appreciate the check-box and an up vote for the effort.

Comment: Hey, we have problem again. It works for a day, then yesterday we didn't use it. And on yesterday night, it didn't work again. We checked everything, it's correct. So we restart the router and reset everything, it works again. This morning, it again doesn't work. So we went to the router's page, trying to getting to the firewall setting. But everytime after we enter the password, instead of jumping to the firewall setting, it jumps back to the main page, making us unable to access to firewall. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: And now when i try to go the firewall setting page, it shows 404 error